# how to add a script in j2me app

Tags: mobile, java-me

Suppose I have a app which called opera j2me. Whenever I visit to abc.com it ask for a user name and password, after putting these details opera j2me prompt me to save user name and password in its manager. Now if I will edit opera j2me and add a script(2nd transparent window) to save any inputs which puts in opera j2me in a .txt file or any readable extension on phone memory or on cloud/server storage. Doesn't matter if second windows prompt to save details.

I have make it more clear in image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzat4.png

Answer (score 0):

12 views no reply?

Is it not possible or what?